# Why does this link not work?

Tags: html, hyperlink

```
<iframe id="video" src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151798532949501" height="360" width="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>


<a href="http://vimeo.com/73449305" target="video">Test</a>
```

I have this code and it does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `<iframe name="video">`

Comment: tried, that does not work either

Comment: Your iframe works for me in chrome. What happens for you? How does it "not work"? blank video element? Do you get errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Cross Origin Restriction? Error in Console?

Comment: Works for me with `name` http://jsfiddle.net/TrKPk/

Comment: @Harry: could be, the policy is quite likely disabled in my browser to allow me to run experiments.

Comment: @Pietu1998: Nope, still doesn't work for me. Just to get it right, you are saying that after the 'Test' link is clicked, the updated video from vimeo shows up right?

Comment: @Harry Yeah, actually in FF the frame seems to go to `about:blank`.

Comment: @harry Yes, That is the behaviour i am expecting

Comment: Interesting (though old) comparison of `id` vs `name` targeting of iframes in various browsers: http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2007-April/010975.html

Comment: This code works <iframe id="video" src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151798532949501" height="360" width="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>


<a href="http://wordpress.org/" target="video">Test</a>

Comment: so does this <iframe id="video" src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151798532949501" height="360" width="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>


<a href="//player.vimeo.com/video/73449305?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" target="video">Test</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link for the vimeo video is not correct, to get the right link look at the embedded code under the "Share" option in vimeo. In this case, the link is: http://player.vimeo.com/video/73449305

so replace it with the following:

```
<iframe name="video" src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151798532949501" height="360" width="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<a href="//player.vimeo.com/video/73449305?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" target="video">Test</a>
```

*Edit: As pointed out by  Pietu1998, iframe name should be set to video for it to properly work in Firefox.*

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Spot on

Comment: Firefox still opens a new tab. Works with `name="video"` in `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try changing the src with JavaScript?

HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151798532949501"></iframe>

<a href="#" onclick="changeVideo('http://vimeo.com/73449305');">Test</a>
```

JavaScript

```
function changeVideo(loc) {
document.getElementById['videoframe'].src = loc;
}
```

By the way some sites do not allow you to open them in iframe (security reasons - clickjacking) (the html way you did it)

Hope this helps :)